# io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions vs io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions vs cucumber.api.CucumberOptions which one should i choose

Tags: testng, cucumber-junit

I am new to cucumber.I am trying to run cucumber feature files using testng in maven project. for which, in my pom.xml file, I have dependencies for 
 TestNG,cucumber,junit,cucumber junit,cucumber java,selenium java

I have imported `CucumberOptions` from `io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions` and when i used  attribute format , eclipse is throwing error that format *The attribute format is undefined for the annotation type CucumberOptions*
 Also eclipse is giving me options to import CucumberOptions from 3 different classes namely

```
io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions
io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions
cucumber.api.CucumberOptions

I have 2 questions.
```

1. All these 3 packages seems do not support format attribute, what 
   should i do , if i want to have below o/p

   ```
   format = {
   "pretty",
   "html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-pretty",
   "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json",
   "rerun:target/cucumber-reports/rerun.txt"
   }
   ```
2. I am completely clue less when to use each of these package for what 
   scenario .  Please help me.

tried googling for info, few blogs said format is deprecated and now we need to use pretty, at the same time few say we should use format for generating output in different formats

```
package com.qa.testngcucumberrunner;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
@CucumberOptions(
dryRun=false,
monochrome=true,
strict=true,
features={"./src/test/resources/com/qa/features"},
glue={"com.qa.stepdef"},
plugin={"json:target/cucumber- 
reports/CucumberTestReport.json"},
format = {
"pretty",
"html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-pretty",
"json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json",
"rerun:target/cucumber-reports/rerun.txt"
} 
)
public class TestRunner {}
```

Expectation:
    Want to know when should i use which import 
    Also want to know what should i do to get report in html,json,return 
    formates as mentioned in TestRunner file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am new to cucumber.

Have a look at the https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/

> I am trying to run cucumber feature files using testng in maven project. for which, in my pom.xml file, I have dependencies for TestNG,cucumber,junit,cucumber junit,cucumber java,selenium java

Each dependency provides a bit of functionality. You should only add dependencies for the bits you need. For example `cucumber-java` dependency gives you the `@Given`, `@When`, `@Then` annotations. The `cucumber-junit` and `cucumber-testng` modules provide integration with JUnit and TestNG respectively.

It is unlikely that you are using both. So if you are testing with TestNG you should use `cucumber-testng` and `cucumber-java` and remove the dependency on `cucumber-junit`. The other way around if you are testing with JUnit you should use `cucumber-junit` and `cucumber-java` and remove `cucumber-testng`.

> Want to know when should i use which import

Your IDE should tell you that `cucumber.api.CucumberOptions` is deprecated. So if you are using JUnit you use `io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions` and if using TestNG `io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions`.

> All these 3 packages seems do not support format attribute

The `format` attribute was replaced with `plugin`.

Now I can't work out if you are using JUnit or TestNG so you'll have to pick:

- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit
- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/testng